# Adding value from th tag and set total in the final column javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

> I have values from my database and in my view I have added one column
>   added for the total or average value.In every rows, it has 3 columns
>   with values.In database there is no column for average yet instead of
>   putting  in database, I only put in my blade.php. How could i possibly
>   do it in javascript?It seems like i don't know what to start since I'm
>   not a master in java.

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($card['AllGrade'] as $subject)
    <tr>
      <th colspan="4">{!! $subject['subject'] !!}</th>
      <th colspan="2" >{!! $subject['term_1'] !!}</th>
      <th colspan="2" >{!! $subject['term_2'] !!}</th>
      <th colspan="2" >{!! $subject['term_3'] !!}</th>
      <th colspan="2" name ="ave" id ="ave" value=""> total value here</th>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: What's wrong with doing it in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should not code like this, You can use php code to add/average the result.Because you are expecting you can check the code given here. Just add this code to your blade file and of-course use Jquery

```
$("tbody tr").each(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $(this).children('th').not(':first').not(':last').each(function () {
        //"this" is the current element in the loop
        var number = parseInt($(this).html());
        total += number;
    });
    $(this).children('th').last().html(total);
});
```

Comment: By using  php, I have tried it using php snippet code inside blade but the problem is i dont know how to pass value of html element inside php.Example foo is the ID or name element and use $_GET['foo'] wont  even work?How do i pass it?

Comment: Thank you sir, is very useful and its working now. I'm just curios on how to pass value of html element in php inside blade.